# Directly vs indirectly nested structs

Tags: xml, go, struct, nested

In the Go [documentation for xml:Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) there is an example that unmarshals this xml

```
    <Person>
        <FullName>Grace R. Emlin</FullName>
        <Company>Example Inc.</Company>
        <Email where="home">
            <Addr>gre@example.com</Addr>
        </Email>
        <Email where='work'>
            <Addr>gre@work.com</Addr>
        </Email>
        <Group>
            <Value>Friends</Value>
            <Value>Squash</Value>
        </Group>
        <City>Hanga Roa</City>
        <State>Easter Island</State>
    </Person>
```

using these structs

```
    type Address struct {
        City, State string
    }
    type Result struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Person"`
        Name    string   `xml:"FullName"`
        Phone   string
        Email   []Email
        Groups  []string `xml:"Group>Value"`
        Address
    }
```

Note that `Result` contains a reference to the separately defined `Address`. Obviously, this code works.

---

When I try to unmarshal this xml

```
<C>
  <D>
    <E>Fred</E>
    <F>42</F>
  </D>
</C>
```

using these structs

```
type D struct { 
  E string
  F int
}
type C struct {   // Compiles OK but result empty.
  D 
}
```

I get empty results `{{ 0}}`. However the struct below works OK producing `{{Fred 42}}`

```
type C struct {   // This works.
  D struct { 
    E string
    F int
  }
}
```

See [Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/acgMALHFrT).

Am I missing some subtle point about structs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
type C struct {
    D
}
```

This is called [embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) (`D` is an *anonymous* field or *embedded* field). You may think of this as if the fields (and methods) of the embedded type become part of the embedder type (they get *promoted*). So in this case it's "legal" to write `C.E` and `C.F`.

When you do:

```
type C struct {
    D struct {
      E string
      F int
    }
}
```

This is *not* embedding (or "nesting"). Here `D` is a "regular", *named* field of the `C` type. `D` is the name of the field, which is followed by an anonymous [type literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types), the type of the field. Here it is not legal to write `C.E` nor `C.F`, only `C.D.E` and `C.D.F`. And this is the proper mapping of the XML structure you try to unmarshal, hence this works (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VNULprMYcW)).

Note that if you change the embedding to a regular field, it will also work (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RsIDF8sZic)):

```
type C struct {
    D D
}
```

Also note that you can skip the whole `D` wrapper struct if you specify the XML element paths in the field tags:

```
type C struct {
    E string `xml:"D>E"`
    F int    `xml:"D>F"`
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BMQIaNSMXA).